# Make <span> dont overlap each other

Tags: html, css

How can I make the  dont overlap each other on the thumbnail image?

[image: This is the overlapping]

Supposedly the span stay on their on their own image like this
[image]

Here is my CSS

```
.date-img {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #054a8f;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 5px;
    top: 90px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<li class="clearfix span12">
 <span class="date-img"> 19 <br>Oct</span>
<div class="rsepro-image">
<div class="overlay-calendar-img"> 
<img src="https://event-mbpp.aidan.work/components/com_rseventspro/assets/images/events/thumbs/100/450a0c399c52f59dfc867bf413a6951d.jpg" alt="Program City Walk" width="70">
</div>
</div>
<a target="_blank" href="/index.php/ms/component/rseventspro/event/1-program-city-walk?Itemid=101">Program City Walk</a> <br>
<small>Wednesday, October 10, 12:00 AM - 12:00 AM</small>
</li>
```

You can also refer here - https://event-mbpp.aidan.work/

Comment: If you are a Joomla developer, you may like to extend your Stack Exchange participation to include [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

i have gone through link

just change css class as,

```
.date-img {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #054a8f;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    left: -117px;
    top: 25px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Its not working. have you seen the result if you apply your css on that class?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `position: absolute`, which makes them overlap, as they are absolutely positioned. Right now, any siblings will be overlapped.

But `absolute` refers either to the page, or to the closest parent item that has a `position` rule applied.

So a quick and dirty fix will be setting your list items' position to relative: this will make the subsequent absolute rule refer to their container (you may have to adjust the offsets though):

```
.rsepro_upcoming li {
  position:relative;
}
```

Note that the `position:relative` is the default for lists so it shouldn't have other side effects.

A better approach would be using [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Comment: by the way, this is a css question, you might want to remove the Joomla tag